# GoogleMaps 2.1.1 file not found error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

In my project I have updated the google maps framework using cocoapods from v1.13 to v2.1.1 and suddenly found this error.

`#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> file not found`

Don't know why its showing this error.
I tried running the google sample project with googlemaps 2.1.1

```
pod try googleMaps
```

and while running the sample project, still its showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.0'
```

**Update:**
Instead of `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` use:

```
@import GoogleMaps;
```

Refer this [GoogleMaps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map)

Comment: still its installing 2.1.1

Comment: which version you want?

Comment: i tried using your code but still its installing v2.1.1 and actually i want to use this latest version but still that file not found error persists.

Comment: Is it throwing the same error with @import GoogleMaps?

Comment: actually now i figured it out - earlier the googlemaps version was 1.3 and when i tried to update the pod i got this not found error. Finally then i removed that pod and forcefully added `pod 'GoogleMaps, '2.1.1'` for that specific version and now its done.

Comment: But you said earlier that it's already installing 2.1.1, what did you do different this time to make it work?

Comment: this time i commented that pod to make it removed and then after cleaning, i added this line `pod 'GoogleMaps, '2.1.1'` (_here there is no `~>` sign before version number_) and finally it worked.